# Is more or less efficient to use a stand alone function than a callback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, callback

I'm new to JavaScript and recently learned about callbacks via a tutorial. The instructor mentioned that callbacks are used everywhere in code amongst JavaScript developers. What I understand so far is that these callbacks store a function within a function to be executed at a later time, but wouldn't it be simpler and more efficient to store a value in a variable and create a function that logs your desired output? Can’t the callback alternative (typed below) be executed at a later time as well?

```js
// Callback Example:
     
function callbackExample(name, callback){
    log(callback(name)); 
}

callbackExample('Adee Otana', function(name){
    return 'Hello ' + name; 
}); 
     
     
// Alternative: 

let name = 'Adee'; 
 
function callbackAlt(name){
    log('Hello ' +  name); 
}
 
callbackAlt(name);
```

Comment: With the `callbackAlt`, it is limited in what it can log. It will always be `"Hello"` followed by some text. With `callbackExample`, additional logic can be used to determine what the logged output should be and gives the developer more flexibility. The usefulness might be more obvious for functions like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#examples), which allows you to use a callback to define what elements should be kept/removed from an array. Filter is then able to use the callback to make a decision

Comment: no, the stuff about callback functions has nothing to do with storing a function in another function, it's just the address of the function to be called back. there is no duplicate code.

Comment: `callbackExample` is a pretty bad example.